# ASP.net adding multiple triggers for update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got an update panel in my master page.
in my child page i am trying to upload a file using fileupload control.
page is submitted using a link button called lnkSaveRequest. upon submission page throws a lnkComplete pop up button and think that is preventing my file from being uploaded.
when I try to add both lnkSaveRequest and lnkComplete  in triggers

```
UpdatePanel updatePanel = Page.Master.FindControl("up") as UpdatePanel;
UpdatePanelControlTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = lnkSaveRequest.UniqueID;
trigger.ControlID = lnkComplete.UniqueID;
updatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

I get the following error

> *Control with ID 'lnkComplete' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement
>   either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or
>   IPostBackEventHandler*

if I remove the lnkComplete from trigger code , I don't get any error but the file doesnt get uploaded.

Any help much appreciated. or if anyone knows other ways of dealign with update panels in master page please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check remark section in those links, **read carefully**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.postbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

'Use the RegisterPostBackControl method of the ScriptManager control to programmatically register a postback control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Sample postback trigger:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx